# Refactoring PySpark to Snowflake Snowpark code

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Most of code is written in PySpark to be executed on Databricks.

I am evaluating SnowFlake with it's ability to execute Python with Snowpark.

Can someone let me know how I might go about refactoring the following PySpark function to Snowpark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

def checkHiveTableExists(tableName,stageName="base"): 
  
  try:
    spark.sql(f"describe {stageName}{tableName}")
    return True
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error was thrown, <<{e}>>")
    return False
```

My attempt is a follows:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
from snowflake.snowpark import session


def checkHiveTableExists(tableName,stageName="base"): 
 

  try:
    spark.sql(f"describe {stageName}{tableName}")
    return True
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error was thrown, <<{e}>>")
    return False
  
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    return checkHiveTableExists(False)
```

But it failed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original code:

```
def checkHiveTableExists(tableName,stageName="base"): 
  
  try:
    spark.sql(f"describe {stageName}{tableName}")
    return True
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error was thrown, <<{e}>>")
    return False
```

Copy-paste approach into Snowflake will not work.

- There is no `spark` module
- the direct SQL is also different `DESC ...` => `DESC TABLE ...`

The original code itself is somehow tricky, because for object existence is uses query to describe the object

Second: `describe {stageName}{tableName}` string interpolation makes it prone to SQL Injection - somebody could try to call it as `checkHivetableExists("someName'; DROP TABLE ...")`

---

When translating code the focus should be on behavior.

Personally I would perform a metadata check [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables) and see if row exists - user calling this code needs to have permission to access this table.

Anyway, trying to be as as close as possible to original code:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def checkTableExists(session: snowpark.Session, tableName, schemaName="BASE"): 
  try:
    session.sql(f"DESC TABLE IDENTIFIER('{schemaName}.{tableName}')").collect()
    return True
  except Exception as e:
    #print(f"An error was thrown, <<{e}>>")
    return False
  
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    return checkTableExists(session, 'TEST')
```

Comment: Hi @Lukasz, thanks reaching out. I tried your code, but got the following error ```Handler did not return a Snowpark DataFrame. Return a DataFrame from the handler or change the return type for the Python worksheet.```

Comment: @Patterson Because it is returning to Worksheet a boolean and not a data frame. The error is self-explanatory `Settings -> Return Type -> String`